# Android socket message

Tags: android, sockets, chat

i have two application that i am trying to connect using sockets i am trying to test it but the problem is that it only works when i am using the same wifi connection on the phone. one phone has the client and the other on has the server. my question is how do i connect it when they not on the same wifi network

This is the client

```
package com.example.androidclient;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textResponse;
    EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort; 
    Button buttonConnect, buttonClear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        editTextPort = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
        buttonConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        buttonClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        textResponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);

        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textResponse.setText("");
            }});
    }

    OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = 
            new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(
                            editTextAddress.getText().toString(),
                            Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString()));
                    myClientTask.execute();
                }};

    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response = "";

        MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = 
                        new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead;
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                /*
                 * notice:
                 * inputStream.read() will block if no data return
                 */
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            }finally{
                if(socket != null){
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            textResponse.setText(response);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}
```

this i the severcode

```
package com.example.androidserversocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView info, infoip, msg;
    String message = "";
    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        infoip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);

        infoip.setText(getIpAddress());

        Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
        socketServerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

        static final int SocketServerPORT = 3333;
        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        info.setText("I'm waiting here: "
                                + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
                    }
                });

                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    count++;
                    message += "#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()
                            + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n";

                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            msg.setText(message);
                        }
                    });

                    SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread = new SocketServerReplyThread(
                            socket, count);
                    socketServerReplyThread.run();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private class SocketServerReplyThread extends Thread {

        private Socket hostThreadSocket;
        int cnt;

        SocketServerReplyThread(Socket socket, int c) {
            hostThreadSocket = socket;
            cnt = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            OutputStream outputStream;
            String msgReply = "Hello from Android, you are #" + cnt;

            try {
                outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
                PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
                printStream.print(msgReply);
                printStream.close();

                message += "replayed: " + msgReply + "\n";

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        msg.setText(message);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
            }

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    msg.setText(message);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    private String getIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                        .nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                        .getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += "SiteLocalAddress: " 
                                + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }

        return ip;
    }
}
```

i got the idea from this site
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-server.html

Comment: "does not go" is not a good error description. Please provide details on what works and what does not work including maybe an error message. Also, have you made sure that the phones can reach each other network-wise? And no, that both have internet connection is not necessarily enough

Comment: @arinze You can connect the client with the server only when they are network-wise reachable. By using the same wifi connection it means that they are in the same local network and they are reachable using local ip address. But when are they are in different wifi connections you should port forward in your router to your mobile where the server device listens and specifying the public ip address of the router in your client. Make sure that you use ephemeral port. When you are not connected to router and if you are using mobile data connection, some network data providers might block ports.

Comment: can you show me an example how do i use ephermeral port. or should i just use google push notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really have is communication between two components (activities in this case) the same device. I'm not sure if these two components are part of the same app or are installed separately but that does not matter as they will anyway not work across devices. Your server is simply a socket listener.

To implement device to device communication, you will need an actual server up and running outside of the device that the devices can communicate to (like maybe deploy it on your desktop while you are on wifi and let the devices find it or do the real deal and deploy it on a real server - may cost money). An example app for this can be found at https://github.com/Pirngruber/AndroidIM. The app is written for Android and uses Eclipse type builds but other than that the source code works well - I've used this in the past.

Or you can look into push messaging applications. tutorials for chat applications using Google Cloud messaging library are dime a dozen. While they do not use servers in the sense that we deploy applications, they use google's push system to send and receive messages.

Comment: i am finding it hard to understand the code in link you kept